# How to create an exclude constraint with a daterange using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I know that just using raw sql, I can add an exclude constraint like so:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_daterange_constraint
EXCLUDE  USING gist
( foo WITH =, 
  daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') WITH &&
);
```

However, I need to be able to do the same with sqlalchemy. What I currently have (which does not work) in my table args is:

```
    __table_args__ = (
    postgresql.ExcludeConstraint(
        ("foo", "="),
        (DateRange("start_date", "end_date", bounds="[]"), "&&"),
        name="unique_daterange_constraint",
        using="gist",
    ),
)
```

DateRange is imported from psycopg2.extras, as it's my understanding that that is how to replicate the postgres daterange type as used in the sql above.

My stacktrace, when attempting to create an alembic migration file tells me that the daterange section is wrong with

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'psycopg2._range.DateRange'> instead
```

I know that a potential way I could handle this (since it really wants a column where I'm putting the DateRange) is to create a daterange column and a trigger that upon insert or update populates my daterange column with the start and end dates, but it feels like I shouldn't have to do that. It seems that if I can simply define a daterange using existing columns in sql, I should be able to using sqlalchemy as well.

Is there any way to achieve this the way I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since an SQL expression object is expected, provide one. Assuming you have named the column attributes the same as their DB counterparts, and define `Table` arguments after your column definitions:

```
__table_args__ = (
    postgresql.ExcludeConstraint(
        ("foo", "="),
        (func.daterange(start_date, end_date, "[]"), "&&"),
        name="unique_daterange_constraint",
        using="gist",
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For the sake of consistency in the code base, I ended up using this approach but with MyTable.__table__.append_constraint() after the class definition, instead of dumping the table_args down at the bottom to deal with the using before defined issue with column names.

Comment: for the record, it freaks out when a bounds argument is supplied. It seems that I have to just keep the two column names and then properly write the bounds in an op.execute in the alembic migration (since the constraint doesn't get auto-added to the migration anyway)

Comment: How does it freak out? Another solution to the "use before" issue would be to use the light weight `sqlalchemy.column()` to produce the column references.

Comment: For some reason in SA 1.4.39 range bounds string (`'[]'`) was compiled either as `%(daterange_1)s` using psycopg2 2.9.6 or as `%s` using asyncpg 0.26.0, I had to wrap it into `sqlalchemy.text`.

Comment: That is as it should be. Those were placeholders that are then replaced with the actual value when the query is executed. But maybe you mean that this replacing did not happen?