# How prevent inserting overlapping integer ranges flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am writing Python Flask app backed by SQLAlchemy.

Here is my model

```
class IntervalModel(BaseModel):
    """Interval table"""

    __tablename__ = 'interval'

    start = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, nullable=False)
    end = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, nullable=False)

    desc = db.Column(db.String(256), index=True, nullable=True)
```

However, intervals must be unique and **must not overlap**.

For example, if I insert first correct entries:

```
postgres=# select * from interval;
 id | start | end 
----+-------+--------
  1 |     2 |      8
  2 |     9 |     20
(2 rows)
```

Then if someone tries to **INSERT** entries like

```
start: 3    end: 5  (should be invalid)
start: 7    end: 16 (should be invalid)
```

I learnt that it is possible to create some kind of **constraint** but I did not manage to create one.

Can someone guide me to a right direction ?

Thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461002/how-to-create-an-exclude-constraint-with-a-daterange-using-sqlalchemy has some pointers to using exclusion constraints.

Comment: thanks, I found quite a lot of solutions when it comes to datetime however, I did not manage to find one when it comes to INT @IljaEverilä

Comment: Speaking of integers, your model currently stores them as strings. It would likely make life easier to just store them as numbers (integers, numeric, etc.).

Comment: I know, this could be converted to INT but this does not resolve my use case.

Comment: In addition to date ranges,  as in the reference above,  Postgres also provides [Integer Ranges](https://ww.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN). Integer ranges have **exactly** for same functionality date ranges. Just substitute your integer values for for dates used.